# Add to list on enter knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js, custom-binding

I am unable to get the names to add to the list after hitting enter, yet it still adds when clicking "Add Name". Any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/someyoungideas/WWpcC/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this code is that self.people in pushPeople() is undefined (because `this` points to the input element instead of the view model).

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/WWpcC/22/

Changed `value.call(this);` to `value.call(ko.dataFor(this));`

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/knockoutjs/

Specifically, http://todomvc.com/architecture-examples/knockoutjs/js/app.js

```
var ENTER_KEY = 13;

// a custom binding to handle the enter key (could go in a separate library)
ko.bindingHandlers.enterKey = {
    init: function( element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data ) {
        var wrappedHandler, newValueAccessor;

        // wrap the handler with a check for the enter key
        wrappedHandler = function( data, event ) {
            if ( event.keyCode === ENTER_KEY ) {
                valueAccessor().call( this, data, event );
            }
        };

        // create a valueAccessor with the options that we would want to pass to the event binding
        newValueAccessor = function() {
            return {
                keyup: wrappedHandler
            };
        };

        // call the real event binding's init function
        ko.bindingHandlers.event.init( element, newValueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, data );
    }
};
```

Note this extension is called *enterKey* and not *addOnEnter* which is a more suitable name for a generic piece.

Comment: Great custom handler! Thanks for sharing - saved me time!

Answer (score 1):

Think about submit binding
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/submit-binding.html

It avoids the need to make a custom binding to catch keycode 13
Also you don't need the valueUpdate

html

```
<form data-bind="submit:pushPeople">
 <input type="text" data-bind="value: addPeople, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown'"/>
 <input type="submit" value="Add Name" />
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jnewcomb/umf3f/1/

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

http://jsfiddle.net/KDz6E/

basically your "self"  was a html element, not your view model

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need any custom binding, simple event will be pretty enough!

I've adjusted your example. **UPDATED EXAMPLE:** [**JS FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/dmitry_zaets/WWpcC/36/)

Hope it will helps you.

Regards, Dmitry Zaets.